# Manually triggered Github Action is always being skipped

Tags: github-actions

I have a working Github Action file that build on commits.

I want to be able to manually trigger a build so I only added **"workflow_dispatch"** and got the nice option button visible in the GUI where I can select which branch to manually build.

**But** when I select a branch (**"dev"**) and start the build it always get skipped?!

The yml-file is both in my **"main"** branch and in the desired branch **"dev"**

*My yml-file looks like below and "workflow_dispatch" is the **only** thing I have changed:*

```
name: Build for dev

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - dev

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          submodules: true
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v0.0.1-preview
        with:
          app_build_command: "npm run build-dev"
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_XXXXX }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
          action: "upload"
          ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match you app requirements. ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: "/" # App source code path
          api_location: "api" # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: "dist" # Built app content directory - optional
          ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######
        env:
          NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v0.0.1-preview
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_XXXXX }}
          action: "close"
```

Does anyone know why build is being skipped, or where I can see the reason for it?

**UPDATE:** Screenshot from skipped build:
[image]

**UPDATED! I found solution myself!** I had an if statement in "build_and_deploy_job" so I needed to change it to:

```
if: github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch' || github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
```

Comment: Could you please attach the link to the log of the action execution? It would help determining the problem.

Comment: Repo is private, still there is no log produced - it just say build is skipped.

Comment: Can you add your full workflow?

Comment: I haave just updated this issue now with full yml-file content

Answer (score 4):

I had the same symptom -- my manually run workflow was being marked as "Skipped."

In my case, I had the following condition on each job. This condition only ran the job if the previous workflow in the chain was successful:

```
if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}
```

The above was not satisfied when the workflow was started manually. The following worked for me:

```
if: ${{ github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch' || github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}
```

The above says, "run this job if it was manually started *or* the parent workflow succeeded."